# Vb.net web application , where to put code on web browser close event?

Tags: vb.net, web-applications

I would like to know where to put my vb.net code that executes when the web browser is been closed ?

Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific.

You are looking for an event to execute some code on when some kind of browser closes?

Comment: Changed my subject and question

Comment: To me, it's still not clear what browser you are talking about.
A webbrowser (IE, Chrome, ...)?

Comment: Web browser indeed, I changed that one as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the codebehind on an ASP.Net project (which I assume is what this is) can only execute when it receives some sort of command or event prompting it.  A browser closing is not an event as far as the VB.net is concerned; the codebehind won't even know it's closed, since the browser is clientside and the VB.NET is serverside.  The only thing I can suggest is that you do something like have a timer running that is reset every time a user clicks anywhere or does anything, and that triggers your code when it reaches a certain number (a number it will only reach if the user has been inactive for a certain amount of time).